# Python Upgrade Broke Django

Tags: python, django

I've upgraded Python from 2.5 to 2.7, but the upgrade broke Django.  My Django tests and shell report they can't find the modules.

I tried putting the site-packages with Django on my PYTHONPATH in .bashrc, but this failed to to find MySQLdb.

Do I have to reinstall Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And MySQLdb.

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```

(well, not Django, but why take a chance when it's so easy to do?)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to install MySQLdb, but the setup wants setuptools, whose setup wants zlib, and apparently my installation of Python didn't create the zlib module properly.

Comment: Fixed zlib by installing zlib1g-dev, then reinstalling python.  That gave me setuptools. MySQLdb installation then wanted mysql_conf, which I got by installing libmysqlclient15-dev.  Then I could install MySQLdb, and Django worked.  God bless the various packagers -- seriously, they make incredible things possible -- but this installation was more google-fu than I've needed in a long time.